# Identify (very old) bricks with 2 studs

Tags: part-identification

I have this two bricks I got as a present a while ago, and wanted to know a bit more about them.

**Things I noticed:**

- The material is not entirely hard as today's plastic bricks, some small marks can be seen on the righter one.
- When they are put together, there's a little gap left between them, not smooth and tight as today's bricks.
- I'm pretty sure it's very old.

**What I'd like to know:**

- Year of creation (also estimated is great)
- Material
- Manufacturer
- Anything else interesting about it :)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure these are Lego bricks? Not all brick toys are made by Lego. Usually, Lego bricks have "LEGO" text on each stud (I'm just referring to the post title which mentions "Lego"; consider removing/editing to make it more generic)

Comment: This might deserve the `clone-brands` tag too, but it isn't LEGO-compatible so it doesn't quite fit.

Comment: @chicks I was tempted to use the 'clone-brands' tag aS it seems the most appropriate but seeing how it was produced before LEGO bricks and seems to have indirectly influenced the design I'm not sure what to call it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're called *MiniBrix*.

- Year of creation: *1935*.
- Material: *Rubber*.
- Manufacturer: *Premo Rubber Company*.
- Watch my source informative video by **JangBricks** *[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=32&v=iFELcl75CiY)*, which tells the interesting history of toy bricks before LEGO ;).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

- **Audiophile Bonus**: [*Cool background music from the video*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGmB0ivzxNE). 
  [image]