# Part Identification - What are these bricks?

Tags: clone-brands, vintage

Any idea of what these are? Came in a lot with vintage LEGO, Nintendo Blocks (N&B) and a few other vintage items that tell me this is probably from 60's era.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A picture from [Identify (very old) bricks with 2 studs](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10162/identify-very-old-bricks-with-2-studs) provided me with the answer: It's "American Bricks", the plastic ones, manufactured by "Elgo Plastics, Inc". They date around 1950s.

[image]

Comment: Wow, great find.  Thank you!

Comment: Since you're fairly new, please read https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers - the customary way to say thanks is to mark an answer as "accepted".

Comment: They look more like a later evolution of "American Bricks", called "Playskool Building Bricks" (1970s). The ones in the OP's picture don't have the "American Bricks" logo on them, have more rounded studs, no notches or ridges on the sides, but notches on the anti-studs. Although, they might still have been made by "Elgo", but afaik they'd have "Elgo" engraved on the underside in that case (can't tell from the OP's picture).